# Is Assert.Equal method from xUnit checking the same reference or looking for two different object instances?

Tags: c#, .net, xunit

I started to use xUnit infrastructure.
So I tried to use `void Assert.Equal(string expected, string actual)` method.

```
[Fact]
public void CanChangeProductName()
{
    // Arrange
    var p = new Product()
    {
        Name = "Name",
        Price = 180M
    };
    var new_name = "NewName";
    // Act
    p.Name = (string)new_name.Clone(); // ?
    // Assert
    Assert.Equal(new_name, p.Name);
}
```

And wondered, should I use string.Clone() method to create truly new object instead of comparison the same link to single object?

Comment: Sorry. I really forgot if there creating new object in case of `p.Name = new_name` or just send the same link. If 'No', my question is relevant

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm afraid your comment isn't clear to me - or what you're really asking. Currently you're only checking for string equality - where does `Product` come into this at all? Please clarify your question if possible.

Answer (score 0):

No need to clone to verify the expected behavior

```
[Fact]
public void CanChangeProductName() {
    // Arrange
    var expected = "NewName";
    var subject = new Product() {
        Name = "Name",
        Price = 180M
    };

    // Act
    subject.Name = expected;
    var actual = subject.Name;

    // Assert
    Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
}
```

Now unless there is something special happening within the subject under test that was not shown in the original question, I am not seeing much value in testing that property.